# How can we do Collection proces swith date?

Tags: php

I have date with this format

```
format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

How can i do this

```
$hola == $hi + 10000;
```

Like i add to the current time 10000 seconds ?

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$hi = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$hola == $hi + 10000;
echo $hola;
```

This script gives me a blank page ,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: add seconds to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538670/php-add-seconds-to-a-date)

Comment: Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316784/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use [`DateTime::add()`](http://php.net/manual/datetime.add.php) before formatting it as a string

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT10000S')); // adds 10000 secs
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Also, on the line `$hola == $hi + 10000;` you use a comparison operator. this will throw an error. If you have not set `display_errors` to 1 in your php config, the error will be silenced and a blank page will be returned

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.modify()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) on the `DateTime` object.

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->modify('+10000 seconds');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code you are using comparison operator `==` so its comparing `$hola` **blank variable** with `$hi+10000` which is not correct.

If you are trying to add date with number you can do this:

```
$Date1 = '2010-09-17';
$date = new DateTime($Date1);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); // P1D means a period of 1 day
$Date2 = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

For more info: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php)