# Convert 6 digit number to date

Tags: php

I'm integrating external API which has `expire_in` key with value `179999`. I need to convert the value to date so that I can compare current date with expired date (expired_in). from the API documentation say it expired in 50 Hour. I know that i can just create manually like `strtotime('+50 hour')` but still I want to know how can I convert `179999` to date.

what I try

`\DateTime::createFromFormat('ymd', 179999)->format('Y-m-d')`

but it give me this result `2025-06-07`

Comment: For 179999, what is your expected output date?

Comment: maybe you meant to add that seconds to the current  time?

Comment: @Raptor issued_at `2021-03-16 09:26:49` expected output `2021-03-18 11:26:49`

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538670/php-add-seconds-to-a-date

Comment: @Raptor i didn't know the keyword `add second to time` thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add 179999 seconds to the current date:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->add(new DateInterval('PT179999S')); // adds 179999 secs
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new variable,

`$new = old() + (6 * 23 * 59 * 60);`

6 is the number of days
23 is the number of hours
59 is the number of minutes
60 is the number of seconds

If you want to use CreateFromFormat,

```
$format = 'Y-m-d';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2009-02-15');
echo "Format: $format; " . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

Comment: This is not related to the question at all.

Comment: @Raptor i dont understand how its not related, its right there ....

Comment: Where is the add seconds part? and the number 179999 is not even here

Comment: @Raptor its an example of how he can do it. And its to add hours not seconds

Comment: OP does not ask for adding hours.

Comment: @Raptor he clearly said he wanted to add hours, Read Again!